# fmdb executeUpdate fails

Tags: objective-c

What am I doing wrong? It's a very simple statement but couldn't figure out what causes it to fail

```
    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:appDelegate.databasePath];
    [db open];
        isSuccess = [db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO notes (title, comment, fk) values (?, ?, ?);", title, comment, fkID];
```

exception.name=NSInvalidArgumentException, exception.reason=-[__NSCFString comment]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68a93f

Note.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Note : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *comment;
@property (nonatomic) int fkID;
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing.

```
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO notes (title, comment, fkid) values ('%@', '%@', %i)", title, comment, fkid];
    isSuccess = [db executeUpdate:sql];
```

It works fine.

Comment: You're asking for a SQL Injection attack.

Comment: They specifically tell you not to do it this way. See https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb#data-sanitization

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [FMDB usage](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

```
[db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO notes VALUES (?,?,?)", title, comment, [NSNumber numberWithInt:fkID]];
```

All arguments provided to the `-executeUpdate:` method (or any of the variants that accept a va_list as a parameter) must be objects.